# Нужно создать папку с файлами, название которых будет браться из списка со словами, а также в каждый файл вписать цифру из другого списка

Tags: python, numpy, pathlib

**Вот текст самой задачи:**
Создайте папку task3. Создайте список из 10 строк и список из 10 целых чисел в диапазоне от 0 до 100. Создайте в папке task3 файлы с расширением .txt с названиями из списка со строками. В файлы впишите по одному числу из списка с числами

Почему-то последний файл у меня остается пустой, не знаю, как это исправить

**Вот мой код:**

```
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
path = Path.home() / 'Documents/Python/Parcing/'
task3 = path / 'task3'
task3.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
str10 = ['Honda','Toyota','Nissan','Suzuki','Mitsubishi','Mazda','Infiniti','Lexus','Daihatsu','Datsun']
num10 = np.arange(0, 100, 10)
for i in range(10):
myF = open(str10[i] + '.txt', 'w+')
os.replace(str10[i] + '.txt', '/Users/vladsedov/Documents/Python/Parcing/task3/'+str10[i]+'.txt')   
myF.write(str(num10[i]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
path = Path.home() / 'Documents/Python/Parcing/'
task3 = path / 'task3'
task3.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
str10 = ['Honda','Toyota','Nissan','Suzuki','Mitsubishi','Mazda','Infiniti','Lexus','Daihatsu','Datsun']
num10 = np.arange(0, 100, 10)
for i in range(10):
    #create the file in the task3 directory
    myF = open(task3 / (str10[i] + '.txt'), 'w+')
    #write the number to the file
    myF.write(str(num10[i]))
    #close the file
    myF.close()
```